# search for a character in one column and replace value in another column of matched records

Tags: sed, awk, perl, csv-simple

I have a requirement to find value 2 in column 4 and wherever it matches replace 6th column with '-'sign in the beginning

suppose if i have csv file - file1 like this

```
abc,0,def,1234,ijk
xyz,2,def,2345,abc
ijk,2,def,5678,ijl
```

I need a regular expression which will provide output like:

```
abc,0,def,1234,ijk
xyz,2,def,-2345,abc
ijk,2,def,-5678,ijl
```

How can I do this  using `awk`, `sed` or `perl`

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F',' '$2 == 2 {$4 = "-"$4}1' OFS=',' file
abc,0,def,1234,ijk
xyz,2,def,-2345,abc
ijk,2,def,-5678,ijl
```

A `perl` equivalent:

```
$ perl -F',' -anle '$F[3] = "-".$F[3] if $F[1] == 2; print join ",", @F' file
```

Comment: The awk solution worked perfectly.. thank you very much..